# Move column in CSV powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am a newbie at Powershell and I just figured out how to add a column. I am now looking to have the column `Unique Account Name` put before the `Type0` column:

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | where-Object {$_.Name0 -eq "administrators"} |
Select-Object *,@{Name='Unique Account Name';Expression={'setvalue'}} | 
Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\LGMbestone.csv
```

[image: screenshot showing columns]

Comment: Why does it matter what order the columns are in?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It is more of a personal Preference, I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, what Bill said. Stop using * and just use Select-Object -Property <list of comma-separated properties in the order you want them returned to include the calculated property (Unique Account Name) wherever you want it in the list>

Comment: Yes it is possible. Edit your `Select-Object` and specify the column order you want before calling `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out.